# Javascript Joi Alternatives Array or Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm confused about `Joi` alternatives. I can't figure out how the alternatives are invoked against the item to tb validated.

```
function validateCourse(course) {
    const objectSchema = {
        id: Joi.number().required(),
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };

    const arraySchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object(objectSchema)).required();

    return Joi.alternatives(objectSchema, arraySchema).validate(course);
}
```

This works for the object but not for the array of objects.

```
[ 
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "XY"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "JFK"
  }
]
```

I'm not sure if my array schema is at fault or my use of alternatives?

It appears it is working!  However the invalidation message returned by the Joi when validating an array is vague when compared to validating the object.

```
validating object : "name" length must be at least 3 characters long
validating array : "value" must be an object
```

Which is not completely useful as now I have to potentially check hundreds of items to find the one at fault.

But that's a different issue consider this closed!

Comment: Can you please give an example for the array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your schema. The error you are getting with the array is:

```
"value" must be an object, "value" at position 0 fails because 
[child "name" fails because ["name" length must be at least 3 characters long]]
```

Which is right, your name key must have at least 3 characters.

And, as you asked, you can get the object(s) that failed from the error description or
you can also use [`any.error(err)`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr) in order to keep track of those objects.

For instance, if you want to know the array indexes that failed you can do:

```
  const arraySchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object(objectSchema)).required().error((errors) => {

    const indexes = errors.map((err) => err.path[0]);
    return new Error(`Indexes with error: ${indexes}`)
  })
```

For this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'ABC'
  },
  {
    'id': 22,
    'name': 'ABC'
  },
  {
    'id': 33,
    'name': 'XY'
  },
  {
    'id': 44,
    'name': 'ABC'
  },
  {
    'id': 55,
    'name': 'XY'
  },
]
```

The error will be:

```
Indexes with error: 2,4
```

You can access your error message by doing:

```
validationResult.error.message
```

Don't forget to use `{ abortEarly: false }` in your validation:

```
Joi.alternatives(objectSchema, arraySchema).validate(course, { abortEarly: false })
```

Comment: It was failing but the message was not telling me why, but that was because I was looking in the wrong place.  I was using error.details[0].message to view the message but when validating arrays the message is instead found in error.details[1].message. Spot the difference!

Answer (score 0):

Worked as described for arrays but then displayed nothing for non arrays so I made a small change :

```
const arraySchema = 

Joi.array().items(Joi.object(objectSchema)).required().error((errors) => 
    {
        if (errors[0].path.length)
        {
            const indexes = errors.map((err) => err.path[0]);
            if (indexes.length) return new Error(`Indexes with error: ${indexes}`);
        }
        return errors;
    });
```

So if it's an array I return the array of bad indexes (as you suggested).  But if it's an object I just return { errors } unchanged.